# Cannot change my second monitor resolution to 1366x768

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution

I'm a new Linux user
I just installed ubuntu on my laptop
after it got installed, I connect my second monitor via VGA
and that monitor cant reach 1366x768, it says on the setting that it only can reach 1024x768
I tried to install the graphic driver but it didn't fix the problem
,
my laptop spec
Thinkpad x230
CPU: Intel® Core™ i5-3320M CPU @ 2.60GHz
RAM:8gb

Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Comment: it seems, your laptop have MiniDisplayPort video outpu -- you can try to use it, maybe via some adaptor it is possible to get higher resolution

Comment: @Mori your title states the opposite of your problem.  Please change "can" to "can't".

Answer (score 1):

1366x768 is a very common resolution used on laptops. Indeed your X230 probably has 1366x768 as it's native resolution. It's less common for external panels to use that resolution. They're typically (in 4:3 aspect ratio) 1024x768 (or lower if older, higher if newer) or 1280x720 (in 16:9 aspect ratio). So it's unlikely to be a driver issue, and more of a hardware capability problem. The best course would be to identify the specific make and model of external monitor, and check the manufacturer specifications to see what it's actually capable of.